# java multithreading in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

how to solve the problem in the log cat .. the error says wait time is negative and it crashes on imulator and external device

this is my code in java android activity

```
public void run() {
        long startTime;
        long timeMills;
        long waitTime;
        long totalTime = 0;
        int frameCount = 0;
        long targetTime = 1000/FPS;

        while (running){
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder){
                    this.gamePanel.update();
                    this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if(canvas != null){
                    try {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            timeMills = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
            waitTime = targetTime - timeMills;
            try {
                this.sleep(waitTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            totalTime += System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            frameCount++;
            if(frameCount == FPS){
                avrageFPS = 1000 / (totalTime/frameCount) / 1000;
                frameCount = 0;
                totalTime = 0;
                System.out.print(avrageFPS);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the log

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: millis < 0: -136
```

Comment: What is targetTime? It looks like it's dying on this.sleep(waitTime), so your waitTime = targetTime - timeMillis is returning a negative value. You can't wait a negative amount of time.

Comment: tareget time is the target amount of FPS i need the game to run with

Comment: so i make the thread sleep the amount of time left between the thread ending and the target so they reach the needed FPS

Comment: ahmed - what if there isn't any time left (which is the case)?

Comment: yes thats what i though of too and the answer below said that too :) actually no error now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does this:

```
long targetTime = 1000/FPS;

while (...) {
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    ... do lots of work ...
    timeMills = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
    waitTime = targetTime - timeMills;
```

If the time required to prepare and render a frame exceeds `targetTime`, then `waitTime` will be negative.  The complexity of your animation, and the value for `FPS`, affect how likely this is to happen.

The easiest fix is simply:

```
if (waitTime < 0) { waitTime = 0; }
```

That way, if your rendering is taking too long and you're missing deadlines, you don't sleep at all.

A better fix would be to structure the game to run off the display's timing, rather than having a fixed notion of frame rate, and to drop frames when you fall behind.  More information about this can be found in [this appendix](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops) to the graphics architecture doc.

Comment: i will try it now ok

Comment: i go no error and no crashes i didnt think of checking if it is 0 and if it is not .. thank you

Comment: but there is a problem the log output the fps as 0.0  .. why ?

Comment: At the point where you log `avrageFPS`, also log the values of `totalTime` and `frameCount`, then do the computation by hand.

Comment: Now do the log *before* you assign them to zero.

Comment: averageFPS: 0.0
total time: 2561600400
frame count: 30

Comment: ok it worked i got 68 to 75 average fps on imulator ... does that mean that i make my game with this fps number ?